# Need help to get rid of in this PHP code that restricts me from having the same entry in a category in a database. (please help)

Tags: php, sql, database

I need to get rid of the part that restricts me from adding the same value in a field from previous entries. I need to get rid of the part that gives me an error message if the entry matches a value from the database. Can someone please help me?

```
<?php

class DbOperation
{
    private $conn;

    //Constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    //Function to create a new user
    public function createUser($RC, $Date, $Value)
    {
        if (!$this->isUserExist($RC, $Date, $Value)) {
            $password = md5($pass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyInventory (username, password, email, name, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $username, $password, $email, $name, $phone);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return ENTRY_CREATED;
            } else {
                return ENTRY_ALREADY_EXIST;
            }
        } else {
            return ENTRY_ERROR;
        }
    }


    private function isUserExist($username, $email, $phone)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? OR phone = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $phone);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }
```

as you can see in the photo below, every single entry in the database is different. I need to get rid of this and make it so that it is possible for 2 "RC" values to be the same.

[image: x]

Comment: What is `$RC` when you pass it to this function?

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

When `createUser` is called, it first checks if the user already exists (if a record exists in the database with the same RC) by calling `isUserExist`. If you want to allow duplicate RC values, simply remove the if/else statement and only keep the code inside of the `if` block.